# SUMIF function for negative cells returning "too many arguments" error

Tags: excel, sumifs

I want to calculate the sum from negative cells in a separate sheet. However, this is only for certain cells within the sheet not all of them in the column. The table is basically people's hours but I only want to know certain people and can not change the order of the table.

When I use the =SUMIF formula I am getting the error message that there are too many arguments for the function.

This is how my formula looks;

```
=SUMIF('H1'!H3:H18,'H1'!H37,'H1'!H43:H45,'H1'!H48:H52,'H1'!H58:H63,"<0")
```

Does anyone know an alternative way or will I have to do each section individually and then a total of each individual total?

Thanks

Comment: `SUMIF()` only allows one criterion.  You will want to change it to a `SUMIFS()`  which has a slightly different order.

Comment: ... AND you need to make all the ranges the same size.

Comment: btw, the criteria range(s) and sum range are reversed in SUMIFS.

Comment: Also since both SUMIFS and SUMIF, require the various ranges to be the same size, you will need to do separate functions for each area.

Comment: Thanks guys I thought the ranges might be a problem, no worries I will do each area separate and hide the cells. Thanks for the help.